# how to make datagrid Visibility is Collapsed in codebehind

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i have data grid. 
now here i am checking the  condition if Companyrows.count  is  zero . if count is zero make data grid.visible  is  false.

```
List<Employee> Companyrows = new List<Employee>();

 if (Companyrows.Count == 0)
            {
                dgrdRowDetail.Visibility = "Collapsed";
// getting error
 //  convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Visibility'   
            }
            else
            {
                dgrdRowDetail.ItemsSource = Companyrows;
            }
```

any help how to solve this issue  would be great 
 thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Collapsed" isn't it a string?

you have to declare the collapsed as following:

```
dgrdRowDetail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```